# How to provide a parameter to a router in django rest API?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So the url I am trying to achieve looks like this:

```
127.0.01:8000/api/tech/?belongs=id
```

My router looks like this:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('tech', TechViewSet, basename="tech")

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    re_path(r'^tech/(?P<belongs>)$', include(router.urls), name="info"),
```

My viewset looks like this (Also has a retrieve and list functions):

```
@action(detail=True, url_path='^tech/(?P<belongs>)$', methods=['get'])
    def retrieve1(self, request, group=None):
          pass
```

And the router is obviously included in urls.py of main project

How to get this url working.. 127.0.01:8000/api/tech/?belongs=id

Please help. and Im sorry, I'm still learning and the routing part is confusing..

Thankyou so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little tricky without knowing your model structure. But if you're using your `get` parameters for filtering you can use `django_filters` to do the heavy lifting for you. Something like this:

`pip install django-filter`

add this to your rest framework settings:
`'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS':['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend']`

Then in your `TechViewSet` you can add `filterset_fields`:

```
class TechViewSet:
    <your other variables>
    filterset_fields = ['belongs',]
```

you can then add query parameters `?belongs=<some_id>` to your url and your results will be filtered.

docs:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend

Comment: Tried doing that, but doesn't work :( Is my re_path wrong?

Comment: @nar-007 I think you can remove the re_path from urlpatterns and just include the router